# <expandproperties /> and encoding with phing

Tags: php, unicode, phing

I have a static application (html/js) that I must put online in two different languages. While it's not hard to copy the whole directory twice and replace each string, it's kind of boring and I expect to see regular changes on this project.

Thus I considered building the two versions of the project (fr and nl) with phing. The idea would be to use a `<filterchain><expandproperties />`, and load the translations from a property files.

It works quite well, but for one thing:
**unicode characters are represented as \uXXX**, which, obviously, is not what I want...

Any idea on how I can fix this ? An excerpt of the build.xml can be found here: http://pastebin.com/2uWHaHvi

**SOLUTION**: It turns out that it's alright for phing. The problem was that my IDE replaced the character transparently with its \uXXX equivalent. If you are having the same problem, try opening the file with a simple text editor.

Comment: can you post a complete use case scenario? showing the properties file and the phing file where you call the filterchain and expandproperties tasks

Comment: I posted the interesting part of the build.xml.
I can't disclose more as I'm under NDA...

Comment: please post your answer as answer, not as an edit to your question.